# Connect to multiple Mongodb Databases

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, database-connection

I want to add data to different databases of mongodb at runtime depending on the request. How can i connect to multiple databases in nodejs at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

For **MongoDB**, IN **NodeJS**, you cannot connect to multiple databases at once, 
But I suppose you want to add data to different databases, for that you do like this article :-

> https://medium.com/@rajamanii/connecting-multiple-database-in-nodejs-with-mongodb-and-mongoose-d88574fcd5a3